# A Few Links On My Webpage Do Not Work

Tags: hyperlink

On my newly created [webpage](http://www.rockwellutilities.com/), I have a column of links that all work except for the top two. I have double checked the code and all of it seems to be uniform. I am not too sure why it is not allowing me to click on the two links at the top, but the rest seem to be working perfectly. If anyone could take a crack at what the problem may be I would really appreciate it! I have pasted the section of the code that I thought might contain the problem! Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPEhtml>
<html>

    <head>
        <title> Rockwell Utilities </title>
        <link href="rockwell.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>

    <div class="pos_top"><div id="bubbles"><img src="/rockwell/sepiawater.jpg" alt="Water Drop" height="250" width="1000"/></div></div>
    <div id="header"><div id="logo"><img src="/rockwell/Rockwellnewnewedit.png" alt="Rockwell Utilities" height="400" width="500" /></div></div>

    </body>


        <div id="wrapper">
            <h1> Rockwell Utilities Welcomes You! </h1>     
    <div id="intro">

            <p>Rockwell Utilities is your number one choice in water and sewage.<br> We provide service to the Lakemoor, Illinois area,
            <br>and have since 2007.
            </p>    

            <img src="/rockwell/award.png" alt="Illinois Department of Health" height="200" width="500"/>
             <a href="http://www.idph.state.il.us/public/press12/2011_Fluoridation_award_list.pdf"> <p>Rockwell 
            Utilities wins Illinois Department of Health Community Water Fluoridation Award four consecutive years!</p>
            </a>

    </div>          
            <div id="navigation_sidebar">


                    <div id="navigation_links">
                        <p>
                            <a href="email.html" title="Email Us"><img src="/rockwell/emailus.png" alt="Email Us"/></a>
                            <a href="payments.html" title="Pay My Bill"><img src="/rockwell/paymybill.png"alt="Pay My Bill"/></a>
                            <a href="calendar.html" title="Calendar"><img src="/rockwell/calendar.png"alt="Calendar"/></a>
                            <a href="notices.html" title="Notices"><img src="/rockwell/notices.png"alt="Notices"/></a>
                            <a href="paymentop.html" title="Payment Options"><img src="/rockwell/paymentop.png"alt="Payment Options"/></a>
                            <a href="rates.html" title="Our Rates"><img src="/rockwell/ourrates.png"alt="Our Rates"/></a>
                        </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logo (`Rockwellnewnewedit.png`) is overlapping the two links.

Comment: how do i move the links down without completely ruining my layout?

Comment: I see that you've made some edits since I last opened the page; I remember that you had large transparent blocks above and below your logo (that were part of the logo image file).

I hate to discourage you, but I'd recommend redoing your layout from scratch, taking into account modern trends and best practices in Web design. I have to say that your site looks like something straight out of 1999; if you're not confident about that, it's no shame repurposing a [free HTML template](http://www.csstemplatesfree.org/), or using a [premium template](http://themeforest.net?ref=egasimus).

Answer (score 0):

Have you double checked that `email.html` and `payments.html` are in the directory as `calendar.html`, `notices.html`, `paymenttop.html`, and `rates.html`? If the bottom 4 work and the top 2 give you a `404`, that is most likely problem.

Comment: I haven't gotten a 404 error. It's just that the links themselves wont even click. Its as if they arent even links.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this causes the problems you describe, but what catches my eye is the fact that there is no space between the src-attribute value ant the alt attribute, as in:

```
<img src="/rockwell/paymybill.png"alt="Pay My Bill"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://i46.tinypic.com/dpvgo7.png
Your picture is overlapping the two links in this image my suggestion is to shrink the image and use the develop tools to see what is wrong because with that you can see what the picture is doing.